# Django queryset getting all tags of a certain image along with image

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two Django classes, Image and Tag (pardon the formatting) in my webapp as shown below:

```
class Image(models.Model):
image_path = models.CharField(max_length=200)
image_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
y = models.IntegerField(default=0)
num_tags = models.IntegerField(default=0)   
image_score = models.FloatField()
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%d' % self.id 

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("image_path", "image_name")  

class Tag(models.Model):

    TEXT_BRIGHTNESS_CHOICES = (
    ('bright', 'bright'),
    ('dark', 'dark'),
    )

image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
tag_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
y = models.IntegerField(default=0)
width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
textbrightness = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TEXT_BRIGHTNESS_CHOICES, default='dark')
text_alignment = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="horizontal")


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.tag_text
```

I want to return a query of all the Image objects, something along the lines of Image.objects.all(), but in the queryset, would it be possible to also get all Tag objects where Tag.image = Image.id? Sorry, I'm sure this would be real easy in SQL but I'm not sure how to do it here...

EDIT: Thanks for the replies guys, but is there a way to do it so that the QuerySet contains both the Image information and all the Tags associated with it? I'm trying to generate a XML format containing all the information. Example:

```
<image image_path="downloaded_images/1_music_working/">
    <imageName>51rtpUU4meL.jpg</imageName>
    <resolution x="393" y="500" />
    <taggedRectangles>
        #each tag associated with the photo will go here
    </taggedRectangles>
</image>
```

I'm using a Django template to fill out the information. The template looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tagset>
{% for object in query_set %}
    <image image_path="{{object.image_path}}">
    <imageName>{{object.image_name}}</imageName>
    <resolution x="{{object.x}}" y="{{object.y}}" />
    <taggedRectangles>
    </taggedRectangles>
    </image>    
{% endfor %}
</tagset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it didn't occur to me that a QuerySet was iterable... so I just did something like this:

```
for image in Image.objects.all():
        image_data = serialize_image(image)
        myfile.write(image_data)
        all_tags = image.tag_set.all()
        tag_data = serialize_tag(all_tags)
        myfile.write(tag_data)
```

Still trying to learn Python / Django, it's only my 4th week using it really (besides 3 weeks in school). It's a really nice language and makes Java/C code look bloated in comparison :)

Answer (score 1):

[You can follow the ForeignKey relationship "backwards"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) by balling a field with the model name on the other end followed by "_set":

```
image = Image.objects.get(id=1)
tags = image.tag_set.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reverse relation

```
tags = image.tag_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right you could do
`tags = image.tag.all()`